# Azure DocumentDb vs RavenDb

Tags: ravendb, azure-cosmosdb

As .NET developers currently we're using `RavenDb` as our default choice of database, in the `nosql` scenario. Now that Microsoft introduced `DocumentDb`,  a `nosql` document database-as-a-service, we're looking for the differences between the two. Database-as-a-service does seems nice, as we run RavenDb on our own server.

Ayende Rahien as an [interesting post](http://ayende.com/blog/168034/azure-documentdb), but it's a little outdated as it compares with an old `DocumentDb` version. Nevertheless it's still a good read.

**Edit:** After reading [Thoughts on Azure DocumentDB](http://nosqlguy.azurewebsites.net/azure-documentdb-thoughts/) I started doubting [about the pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/documentdb/) of `DocumentDb`. Let's say my data model consists of 7 collections, this means I would have to pay 7 * $25 = **$175 per month!** I must be making some kind of mistake here, right!?

**Edit2:** The idea of the creators of DocumentDb seems to put more than one type of document into a single collection, which seems a bit odd to me after using `ravendb` for a while now. The term `collection` caused some trouble understanding `DocumentDb` pricing as it is something completely different in `DocumentDb` then in `RavenDb`

In which scenario would you choose `DocumentDb` over `RavenDb`?

Comment: RavenDb is available as a service in Azure and AWS - https://cloud.ravendb.net/pricing.

Comment: Check out my comparison "_RavenDB vs Cosmos DB_" at https://alex-klaus.com/cosmosdb-vs-ravendb/

Answer (score 6):

[The post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/03/scaling-a-multi-tenant-application-with-azure-documentdb-2/) recommends that you put a lot more stuff in a single collection than you would otherwise. I'm not sure of the wisdom of that long term, but they propose it as a way to keep costs down. Also, since there is no cross-collection transactional isolation, it might be better if you need to update more than one document at a time, to keep them in the same collection anyway.

Comment: exactly. don't think of a collection as a table that can only accommodate a single type of entity.

Comment: It'd be apt to say DocumentDB's collections are closer to physical partitions than tables. Collections support many entity types (they do not enforce schema). Each collection gets a reserved amount of storage (10gb) and throughput (based on perf tier). You'll find that pricing to be quite competitive when looking at storage and throughput (compare to https://ravenhq.com/pricing.html)

Comment: Yeah, think of them as partitions. That helps. I still wonder about how that impacts the coding and running experience, but I will go with it for now. Will indexes be larger/slower because of this? Or is that only a concern in b-tree indexes, as opposed to the first 3 character hash approach that DDB uses?